# Multiple unpublished commits - Unable to publish any. What's wrong?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-push, git-commit

So I'm using GitHub for Windows. And I have 4 unpublished commits (all 4 are the initial 4 commits). So technically, the repo hasn't been created yet on my GH account. To clarify, here's the commit history:

[image]

When I try to publish any of them, I get an error that:

[image]

When I `git status`, I get this:

[image]

Any one can help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on your repository and choose `Open a shell here`
- In the command prompt, type `git push`. The output should show either a `success` or an error message and suggest you the correct argument for `push`. If it does give you an error (something like `git push origin`), then type that command and your repository should be created on the github server.

Comment: Got an error, tried the command, got another error: http://i.imgur.com/AtrMRWM.png

Comment: Have you created such a repository in github prior to pushing ? I don't seem to see the repository `MoodicPlayer.git` listed [here](https://github.com/thekarangoel?tab=repositories)

Comment: I did, but then removed it.

Comment: You need to create one there before you can push your local change into github.

Comment: Aha,.. seems to work now. Care to explain why it didn't automatically create a repo like it did for any of my previous projects?

Comment: And, my `.settings/` and `.bin/` folders are also published even though they are in `.gitignore` file. Any ideas why, how to fix it?

Comment: Whatever was added to your local github repo would have been pushed to the remote as well. May be you created the .gitignore after adding the `.settings` and `.bin` directories.